# Monobehavior functions list of unity

Tags: unity

I just started unity. Currently, I am familiar with Start() , Update(), Awake(), OnCollosionEnter(), OnTriggerEnter() and FixedUpdate().
Can you give me more functions like these

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of an API is generally a good place to go to if you want to find out the list of functions, types, et cetera in that API.

Unity's [documentation for `MonoBehavior` can be found here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html). It includes a complete list of methods and members for `MonoBehavior`, which can be clicked on to get more details. If the documentation alone is insufficient for describing the purpose of or how to use something you are curious about, it should at least give you enough keywords to do a search on your favorite internet search engine for that topic.

If even that fails to turn up results that answer the questions you have, you can always ask another (more specific) question here.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply search for unity **monobehavior** **callbacks**. you can find the, in link below:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html